# Error "invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)" is shown while install gems by gem install mechanize

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm tried to install gem (mechanize) on my computer by following commands:

```
>> gem install mechanize --platform=ruby
>> gem install mechanize
```

The error

```
ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    "C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)
```

is shown while I trying to install gems (mechanize). And run command line as **Administrator**.

I'v installed the **DevKit** by the commands below (config.xml has been modified of cause)

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
```

Is there any method can fix this error? Thanks in advance.

### Here some OS information:

- OS Version: **Win7 64bit**
- Ruby version: **2.0.0p195 x64**
- DevKit version: **DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx**
- GEM Version: **2.0.3**
- Ruby installed location: **C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64**

The details can be found from screenshot:
[image]

According the [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun), I'v remove the AutoRun from Regedit (**HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor**), but it still cannot work!

```
2013/06/03 10:00:26 PM >> REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
    CompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
    DefaultColor    REG_DWORD    0x0
    EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1
    PathCompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x9
    AutoRun    REG_SZ    (if %ANSICON_VER%==^%ANSICON_VER^% "C:\Marslo\Tools\Software\System\CommandLi
icon" -p)&run C:\WINDOWS\autorun.cmd
    AutoRun_bak    REG_SZ    (if %ANSICON_VER%==^%ANSICON_VER^% "C:\Marslo\Tools\Software\System\Comma
\ansicon" -p)&chcp 437&run C:\WINDOWS\autorun.cmd

2013/06/03 10:01:00 PM >> REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /s

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
    CompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x40
    DefaultColor    REG_DWORD    0x0
    EnableExtensions    REG_DWORD    0x1
    PathCompletionChar    REG_DWORD    0x40
    AutoRun    REG_SZ    %WINDIR%\run.bat

2013/06/03 10:01:05 PM >> REG DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
Delete the registry value AutoRun (Yes/No)? yes
The operation completed successfully.
```

Here details about gem and ruby:

```
2013/06/03 10:15:46 PM >> gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-05-14 patchlevel 195) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: "C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe"
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - C:/Users/jiaoolii/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the reason. Just because there is a **space** in the installation path of Ruby

```
RUBY EXECUTABLE: "C:/Program Files/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe"
```

Re-install the Ruby to the path which doesn't contain space, this error will be fixed.

---

And, of course, `AutoRun` should be removed from `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`.

That's important!

Comment: this probably saved a day of my life if not more. t h a n k y o u

Comment: Glad to hear my answer helped you.

Comment: Note: You don’t really need to reinstall elsewhere (well, at least in my case, I didn’t). Just make sure to use 8.3-paths everywhere, i.e. `C:/Progra~1/`, including `CD Progra~1` etc.

Comment: I can confirm that the long path / path with spaces was the killer for me too, and changing it to use "C:/PROGRA~1/" (for "Program Files"; "Program Files (x86) should be "C:/PROGRA~2") did the trick.

FWIW, I used the excellent Rapid Environment Editor (http://www.rapidee.com/en/) to do this - made it much easier!

Comment: I totally wasn't expecting that, I lost many hours on this. Thanks a lot